# systemctl can't start mysql on centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos, vagrant, chef-infra, mysql-python

I'm trying to start mysql on centos 7. (centos is running in a vagrant box, using vmware-workstation as the provider) I have a chef script which fails trying to start mysql using the chef cookbook.

At this point I'm just trying to ssh into the box and get mysql started manually and here is the output i get:

```
(cms-env)[GISO@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start mysql-cms
Job for mysql-cms.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql-cms.service' and '
journalctl -xn' for details.


[GISO@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl -l status mysql-cms.service
mysql-cms.service - mysql_service[mysql-cms]
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql-cms.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-07-05 18:03:59 EDT; 5h 51mi
n ago
  Process: 11215 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-cms-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=
exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11214 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql-cms/my.cn
f --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11214 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql-cms.service

Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting mysql_service[mysql-c
ms]...
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[11214]: mysqld: [ERROR] Could not o
pen required defaults file: /etc/mysql-cms/my.cnf
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[11214]: mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error
 in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: main proces
s exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: control pro
cess exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start mysql_service[
mysql-cms].
Jul 05 18:03:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql-cms.service entered
 failed state.
```

I've been digging around trying to solve this for hours. Have downloaded all recommended development libraries, etc...Can't figure out what is making this fail. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!
thanks

edit: I was able to dig up some more logs here via `sudo journalctl -l | grep mysql` (I apologize for the formatting)

```
.
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.612681Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.7-rc) starting as process 2447 ...
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[1639]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.718655Z
0 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.740870Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.740950Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.740957Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.740961Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.740989Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.742476Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.747596Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.797073Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chu
nk size = 128M
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.935407Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jul 06 00:43:32 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:32.995995Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread
 priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Jul 06 00:43:33 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:33.309642Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.207332Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.207488Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the f
ile full; Please wait ...
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.341340Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.342346Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s)
are active.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.342359Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.342802Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.398277Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.7 started; log sequence number 2529895
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.406371Z
0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.433314Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from .//ib_buffer_pool
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: main proces
s exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.787281Z
0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.787331Z
0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private
 key
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.788123Z
0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.788187Z
0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.788207Z
0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.788220Z
0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:35.167395Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 150706  0:43:35
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: control pro
cess exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start mysql_service[
mysql-cms].
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql-cms.service entered
 failed state.
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:35.590242Z
0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:35.590343Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: Version: '5.7.7-rc'  socket:
 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Jul 06 00:43:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/mysqld/mysql
d.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jul 06 00:44:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting mysql_service[mysql-c
ms]...
Jul 06 00:44:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5225]: 2015-07-06T04:44:16.187336Z
0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --ex
plicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details)
.
Jul 06 00:44:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5225]: 2015-07-06T04:44:16.191829Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.7-rc) starting as process 5225 ...
Jul 06 00:44:16 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5225]: 2015-07-06T04:44:16.195418Z
0 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
Jul 06 00:44:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: main proces
s exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 06 00:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql-cms.service: control pro
cess exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 06 00:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start mysql_service[
mysql-cms].
Jul 06 00:44:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql-cms.service entered
 failed state.
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service operation timed
 out. Terminating.
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered fa
iled state.
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.996641Z
0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.996671Z
0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.996677Z
0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.996685Z
0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.996806Z
0 [Note] Binlog end
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997418Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997427Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997430Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997438Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997466Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997469Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997474Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997477Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997484Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997489Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997493Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997496Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
Jul 06 00:44:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997500Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997502Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997505Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997507Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997509Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997512Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997515Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997518Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997520Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997523Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997525Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997528Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997530Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997533Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997535Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997537Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997539Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997541Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997544Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997551Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997554Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997557Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997559Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997562Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997565Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997567Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997570Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997628Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:44:59.997751Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time ov
er, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.100746Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to .//ib_buffer_pool
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.101118Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 150706  0:45:00
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.323561Z
0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --ex
plicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details)
.
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.324161Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.7-rc) starting as process 5309 ...
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328538Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328579Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328586Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328590Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328598Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.328885Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.329050Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.330182Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chu
nk size = 128M
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.347015Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.348927Z
0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.348952Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using
 the same InnoDB data or log files.
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.348960Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
Jul 06 00:45:00 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:00.350842Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread
 priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.324411Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2530296
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.328516Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.328550Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.328561Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.328836Z
0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.329473Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.354531Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.370145Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.370338Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the f
ile full; Please wait ...
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.579908Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.581476Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s)
are active.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.581498Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.582462Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.635692Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.7 started; log sequence number 2530296
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.636189Z
0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.639421Z
0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.639453Z
0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private
 key
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.640159Z
0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.640231Z
0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.640254Z
0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.640269Z
0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.648606Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from .//ib_buffer_pool
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.650883Z
0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 150706  0:45:01
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.673495Z
0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: 2015-07-06T04:45:01.674091Z
0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5306]: Version: '5.7.7-rc'  socket:
 '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Jul 06 00:45:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/mysqld/mysql
d.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
```

Comment: Is selinux enabled? what output do you get from `# sestatus`?

Comment: selinux is disabled, one of the many things I've tried :/  `[GISO@localhost ~]$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: what output do you get from `# systemctl -l status mysql-cms.service`

Comment: @RedCricket I don't get much more from that, but I was able to dig up some more logs and have posted them at the end of my question

Comment: Did u ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

CentOS is transitioning mysql to mariadb. Under `/usr/lib/systemd/system` you should find the file `mariadb.service`. Simply run

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Then mysql command operates!

Answer (score 0):

Failed to setup SSL
Jul 06 00:43:34 localhost.localdomain mysqld[2184]: 2015-07-06T04:43:34.787331Z
0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private
 key

That's the core of the problem.

Looks like this is a known issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80335

"For more information, see Section 4.4.5, “mysql_ssl_rsa_setup — Create SSL/RSA "Files”.

You need to run mysql_ssl_rsa_setup.